# Request method "POST" not supported. HTTP 405 - Method Not Allowed

Tags: mvc, jsp, spring

necesito ayuda con un problema que no consigo solucionar.

Una pequeña aplicación montada con Maven, Spring e Hibernate. La idea es una página jsp muestra una serie de filtros para buscar en una BD y mostrar los resultados de la búsqueda. Tenemos una primera estructura simple para probar la conexión con BD pero al hacer la llamada nos devuelve un error:

HTTP 405 - Method Not Allowed
Request method 'POST' not supported

EL jsp sería este:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" %>
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Busqueda</title>
<link href="estilo.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>
    <div id="escudo">
        <img alt="escudo" src="icono.png">
    </div>
    <form:form modelAttribute="puesto">
        <h3>SELECCIONA LOS FILTROS DE BÚSQUEDA</h3>
        <form action="buscar.do" method="post">
            <div>
                <select name="puesto" size="1">
                     <option value="Opcion 1">Opcion 1</option>
                     <option value="Opcion 2">Opcion 2</option>
                     <option value="Opcion 3">Opcion 3</option>
                     <option value="Opcion 4">Opcion 4</option>
                     <option value="Opcion 5">Opcion 5</option>
                 </select>
                 <br/>
                 <br/>
<!--            </div> -->

<!--            <div> -->
                <input type="submit" value="Buscar" name="accion">
                <input type="submit" value="Volver" name="accion">
            </div>

        </form>
    </form:form>
</body>
</html>
```

La acción, el buscar.do debería hacer saltar este Controller:

```
package com.spring.direcciondeportiva.controlador;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

import com.spring.direcciondeportiva.dao.BusquedasDAO;
import com.spring.direcciondeportiva.modelo.Jugador;

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/buscar.do")
public class BuscarController {

    @Autowired
    BusquedasDAO daos;

    @RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public String preparaForm(Model modelo) {
        System.out.println("GET BUSCAR");
        return "buscar";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/buscar.do", method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public String iniciar(@ModelAttribute String puesto, Model modelo) {
        System.out.println("Salta el buscar");
//      if(accion.equalsIgnoreCase("Buscar")) {

            List<Jugador> jugadoresPosicion = daos.busquedaPorPosicion(puesto);
            if(!(jugadoresPosicion.isEmpty()) ){
                modelo.addAttribute("encontrados", jugadoresPosicion);
                return "encontrados";
            }else {
                return "noexiste";
//          }

//      }else if(accion.equalsIgnoreCase("Volver")) {

//          return "inicio";

//      }else {

//          return "error";

        }
    }

}
```

He probado cientos de cosas, he mirado de todo pero no consigo hallar con la solución, ¿Alguien podría echarme una mano?

Gracias

Answer (score 1):

En el formulario estás indicando que se envíe a un método POST mapeado en `/buscar.do`

```
   <form action="buscar.do" method="post">
```

sin embargo en tu controlador estás haciendo un mapeo a nivel de clase:

```
@RequestMapping("/buscar.do")
public class BuscarController {
```

y otro mapeo interior dentro de la clase a nivel de método:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/buscar.do", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public String iniciar(@ModelAttribute String puesto, Model modelo) {
```

por lo que tu método POST está mapeado actualmente en  `/buscar.do/buscar.do`

La solución pasa por cambiar el action del formulario apuntando al mapeado que tienes actualmente para el POST (`/buscar.do/buscar.do`) o bien eliminar el atributo `valor`, del mapeo del método POST, quedando así:

```
@RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.POST)
```